# Table is not display correctly

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to show the one list of element in a table. I create two component the tableComponent and the tableitemComponet. So I do in tableComonent I do:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Name</th>
          <th> Price</th>
          <th>Date</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <app-show-list-item-book *ngFor="let book of books" [book]="book"  (deletebook)="deleteBook($event)" >
        </app-show-list-item-book>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

and the `app-show-list-item-book`:

```
<tr>
        <td>{{ book.name}}</td>
        <td class="align_right">{{ book.price | number : '1.2-2'}}</td>
        <td class="align_right">{{ bool.date| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ book.id }}"/>
    </tr>
```

The problem is that I read the value but they are not correctly display in the table.Anyone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by they are not displaying correctly in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **Attribute** directive to get table properly work

like this way,

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Name</th>
          <th> Price</th>
          <th>Date</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody bookList [book]="books" (deletebook)="deleteBook($event)">

      </tbody>
</table>
```

and in `app-show-list-item-book.html`

```
<tr *ngFor="let book of books" >
        <td>{{ book.id}}</td>
        <td class="align_right">{{ book.name}}</td>
    </tr>
```

in `app-show-list-item-book.ts`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[bookList]',
  template: `<tr *ngFor="let book of books" >
        <td>{{ book.id}}</td>
        <td class="align_right">{{ book.name}}</td>
    </tr>`,
})
export class AppShowListItemBookComponent {
  @Input() books: any;
}
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tasvfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)  demo